# CustomTkinter CKtEntry Can't set background color to transparent

Tags: python, transparency, customtkinter

I am attempting to set the background color (fg_color) to transparent because my CKtEntry widget is sitting atop a label with an image background and I want to be able to see the image background through the CKtEntry widget. Currently the CKtEntry widget and a CKtLabel widget have their "fg_color" set to "transparent", but they both show up with a light gray background. Does "transparent" for "fg_color" not mean the background of the widget will show whatever is behind it?

```
self.bg_image = ctk.CTkImage(
            light_image=Image.open(r"C:\Users\sevil\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\Star Citizen\Old_Crow_Repository\Old-Crow\images\controls_images\bg_miniDisplay.png"),
            dark_image=Image.open(r"C:\Users\sevil\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\Star Citizen\Old_Crow_Repository\Old-Crow\images\controls_images\bg_miniDisplay.png"),
            size=(313, 129)
        )
        # Create a CTkEntry for text input
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=width)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # Create a label to display the image
        self.image_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, image=self.bg_image)
        self.image_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") 

        self.entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self, fg_color="transparent", text_color="black", font=display_font, width=150)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=32, sticky="n")

        # Create a CTkLabel for displaying text
        self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Start X (meters)", fg_color="transparent", text_color="white", font=label_font)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="n")
```

I expected the CKtLabel and CKtEntry widgets to have transparent backgrounds and I would be able to see the background image showing through both widgets.

Comment: In CTk, "transparent" as a color simply means to use the background color of the parent.  Everything in CTk is ultimately implemented using plain Tkinter widgets - which simply do not support any sort of actual transparency between widgets.

Comment: So I assume there would be no way to have a background image show through a CKtEntry widget or any other of the widgets?